# Bitmap ArgumentException: parameter is not valid. bitmap loop memory issue

Tags: c#, memory, graphics, bitmap, argumentexception

I'm trying to make a simple rendering program, it draws on an bitmap, then shows it in a `PictureBox` and repeats. It seems like the `Bitmap` builds up a lot of memory in the system? Non of the solutions I have tried (and found) work, like `Dispose()`, `FileStream`, etc.

I can run the program one time, but when it runs multiple times in a loop it won't work.

If I try `Dispose()` the bitmap makes a weird image to be shown.

1. How can make my loop work, it calculates, then draw on bitmap, then shows the `Bitmap` in a `PictureBox` and then repeat.

   private void renderobjekter(int type)
   {
       Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1400, 800);

   ```
   using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
   {
       for (int objlist = 0; objlist < objektertype[type].GetLength(0); objlist++)
       {
           double d = 0;
           double[,] resultobj = new double[objekter[objektertype[type][objlist]].GetLength(0), rendermatrix.GetLength(1)];

           for (int i = 0; i < resultobj.GetLength(0); i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < resultobj.GetLength(1); j++)
               {
                   d = 0;
                   for (int k = 0; k < rendermatrix.GetLength(0); k++)
                   {
                       d = rendermatrix[k, j] * objekter[objektertype[type][objlist]][i, k] + d;
                   }
                   resultobj[i, j] = d;
               }
           }

           for (int i = 0; i < resultobj.GetLength(0); i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < resultobj.GetLength(1); j++)
               {
                   resultobj[i, j] = resultobj[i, j] / resultobj[i, resultobj.GetLength(1) - 1];
               }
           }

           /*using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
           {
               for (int i = 0; i < resultobj.GetLength(0); i++)
               {
                   if (resultobj[i, 0] < 1 && resultobj[i, 0] > -1 && resultobj[i, 1] < 1 && resultobj[i, 1] > -1 && resultobj[i, 2] < 1 && resultobj[i, 2] > -1)
                   {

                       double x = (resultobj[i, 0] + 1) * ((double)pictureBox1.Width / (double)2);
                       double y = pictureBox1.Height - (resultobj[i, 1] + 1) * ((double)pictureBox1.Height / (double)2);

                       gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                       gr.DrawEllipse(pen1, (float)x, (float)y, 1, 1);

                   }
                   else
                   {

                   }
               }
           }*/

           for (int j = 0; j < navigation[objektertype[type][objlist]].GetLength(0); j++)
           {
               int s_p = navigation[objektertype[type][objlist]][j, 0];
               int n_p = navigation[objektertype[type][objlist]][j, 1];
               double xp = (resultobj[s_p, 0] + 1) * ((double)pictureBox1.Width / (double)2);
               double yp = pictureBox1.Height - (resultobj[s_p, 1] + 1) * ((double)pictureBox1.Height / (double)2);
               double xn = (resultobj[n_p, 0] + 1) * ((double)pictureBox1.Width / (double)2);
               double yn = pictureBox1.Height - (resultobj[n_p, 1] + 1) * ((double)pictureBox1.Height / (double)2);

               if (resultobj[s_p, 0] < -1.2 || resultobj[s_p, 1] > 1.2 & resultobj[n_p, 0] < -1.2 || resultobj[n_p, 1] > 1.2)
               {

               }
               else
               {
                   gr.DrawLine(pen2, (float)xp, (float)yp, (float)xn, (float)yn);
               }
           }
       }
   }

   pictureBox1.Image = bm;
   ```

   }

   private void timer()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
       {
           transformer(1, 1);
           renderobjekter(1);
           //abc();
           label1.Text = i + " ";
       }

Comment: What has the title to do with the question? Is that an exception you get? After a couple of loops or what?

Comment: Try replacing this `Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1400, 800);` with `Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image;` (after initilizing the `pictureBox1.Image`, of course)!

Comment: I get the exception on Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(1400, 800);, when I run the renderobjekter() function multiple times in a loop.

Comment: You still didn't tell us which exception you get. Not how larger the images are. Nor after ca. how many loops it throws..

Comment: Thanks! it works now :D